# Why is GoogleApiClient disconnected when I try to access in OnActivityResult but not elsewhere?

Tags: android, google-api, onactivityresult

When I call in the onActivityResult in a fragment, the GoogleApiClient I have in the parent activity is "not connected".

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == Constants.REQUEST_PLACE_PICKER) {

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            /* User has picked a place, extract data.
               Data is extracted from the returned intent by retrieving a Place object from
               the PlacePicker.
             */
            final Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(data, getActivity());

            SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(Constants.SHARED_PREFS, Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putString("address"+id, address.toString()).commit();
            editor.putString("name"+id, name.toString()).commit();
            Log.d(TAG, "Just picked a location, id=" + id);

            ((AllinOneActivity getActivity()).addGeofenceFromListposition(id); 
     getActivity()).addGeofencesButtonHandler(); // <-- This code that checks mGoogleCLientApi.connected()


            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new LocationListAdapter(getGymLocations(), mListener, this));
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "resultCode is wrong " + "resultCode");

        }

    } else {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

However if I do the same thing in a button in the same fragment class, the thing is connected.

```
    //in onCreateView
    mFab = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.fab);
    mFab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mListener.onListFragmentInteraction(); //<-- Work fine!

        }
    });
```

AFAIK this should be calling the same activity, so why is the client disconnected in the first one but not the second?

```
//In parent Activity
public void onListFragmentInteraction(){
    addGeofencesButtonHandler();
}
public void addGeofencesButtonHandler() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Adding geoFencesButtonHandler click");
    if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "not connected in addgeofence", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    try {
        LocationServices.GeofencingApi.addGeofences(
                mGoogleApiClient,
                // The GeofenceRequest object.
                getGeofencingRequest(),
                // A pending intent that that is reused when calling removeGeofences(). This
                // pending intent is used to generate an intent when a matched geofence
                // transition is observed.
                getGeofencePendingIntent()
        ).setResultCallback(this); // Result processed in onResult().
    } catch (SecurityException securityException) {
        // Catch exception generated if the app does not use ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission.
        logSecurityException(securityException);
    }
}

protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();

}

protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();

}
```

Comment: When exactly are you connecting and disconnecting the GoogleApiClient?

Comment: Can you post src in onStop of fragment and activity?

Comment: In onStart and onStop of the parent Activity

Comment: And how your onActivityResult of Fragment and Activity is getting called?

Comment: onClick in adapter of this fragment launches an activityForResult (Google Place Picker).

Comment: Ohh that means you're launching PlaceAutoComplete activity which calls your activity's onStop disconnecting GoogleApiClient. Now when you come back since @DougStevenson mentioned below GoogleApiConnect is async call you're ending up GoogleApiClient not connected.

Comment: Yeah that seems to solve it. Bit of an oversight on my part, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you connect your GoogleApiClient, it doesn't become connected immediately.  You have to register connection callback listeners to know when the connect is actually complete.

In your case, what's happening is that onActivityResult() is being called by Android *before* your connect from onStart() is complete.  onActivityResult() gets called between onStart() and onResume(), but you can't assume the client connect is finished by the time onActivityResult() is called.

What you need to do instead is remember the result from onActivityResult() in a member variable, then check that value in your connection listener to know when it's safe to use your GoogleApiClient object with that data.

Comment: I didn't think of this, but it makes a lot of sense and I am convinced that you are correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you disconnected api in onStop or ondestroy of activity?